# Template function returning PVOID

Tags: c++, templates

Not sure if this can be done.
I have a example function below that needs to return the template

```
template <class T>
T example(DWORD DW)
{
    PVOID buffer;

    // my code is here sets the buffer

    return static_cast<T>(&buffer);
}
```

Would like to use it like this

```
int iReturn = example<int>(dwSomeDword);
```

Comment: You probably mean something like `return *(static_cast<T *>(buffer));` instead. Is that the intention?

Comment: I suggest mentioning in your question the library that you're using. How are `DWORD` and `PVOID` defined?

Comment: just using the normal windows libs `void*`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Cast a DWORD into T or something more?

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable `&buffer` which is bad. Don't do that. I don't know what you're trying to do, but this is a bad way to do it. You should edit the question to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `buffer` is `void*`. And therefore, using address-of operator: `&buffer` gives you a `void**`. And `void**` can not be `static_cast`ed into `T` (unless you happened to instantiate `example<void**>`, but even then, the returned pointer would be dangling).

This would be syntactically correct:

```
return *static_cast<T*>(buffer);
```

That program casts the void pointer into a pointer to `T` and then dereferences it. But there is no need for this trickery. Simply create a `T` in the first place, operate on it, and then return it:

```
T result;
// my code is here sets the result
return result;
```

This has multiple advantages. The compiler takes care of memory aliasing for you and for the correct construction of the result. This also makes named return value optimization possible which allows eliding the copy.